# SharePoint Requirements

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint. I need a workflow portal web application. Please someone guide in intalling the sharepoint and what are the hardware and software requirements for working 
in SharePoint.

Please let me know which is better either Windows SharePoint Services or MOSS2007 for creating web application portal

Comment: you should accept the answer from Robert MacLean, and mark it as answered, this is pretty much the best answer for your question

Answer (score 5):

Deployment Guide: [Deployment Guide Download](http://technet2.microsoft.com/Office/logredir.aspx?MODE=CT&CTT=ToExternal&target=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkId%3D79589%26clcid%3D0x409&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet2.microsoft.com%2FOffice%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F8fe98aa3-23cd-4175-aa45-760e83e8a3bc1033.mspx&reldir=en-us%2Flibrary)

Requirements

- WSS 3.0: [WSS System Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx)
- MOSS 2007: [MOSS System Requirements](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101945391033.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you need either Windows SharePoint Services (WSS), which is free as in beer and can be downloaded from Microsoft, or Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS), which is not free and contains WSS plus 'enterprise' features such as Excel Server (for web access to Excel sheets), Forms Server (for InfoPath), lots of site templates and goodies and all the Business Intelligence stuff.

For development, you need Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 and most likely the SharePoint SDK.

As a side note, I've never been able to code a MOSS Workflow in a machine that does not have all the server stuff installed, so I recommend you set up a vmware or virtual pc box with win2003 server + sql server + active directory + sharepoint if you have to develop workflows.

As for system requirements, that entirely depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) is free as long as you have the Windows Server 2003 licence. You can do a lot with WSS and especially with smaller companies could be enough for their requirements.

MOSS 2007 has extra functionality built on top of WSS for example a more scalable search architecture, Forms server and much more. Larger companies are more than likely going to pay the extra for MOSS license.

If your a company somewhere in between as many are, then you need to go through the cost/benefit of MOSS for your requirements.

The answer to which is better will be similar to asking the same question about many other things - Which is better, Red or Blue? - It depends.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some very good articles I've come across:

[Miscrosft's SharePoint Capacity Planning Tool Executive Overview (this one is very nice!)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb961988%28v=technet.10%29)

[Dell's SharePoint 2007 Sizing Guide (PDF) (very nice)](https://www.dell.com/nl-nl)

[SharePoint Capacity Planning Key Info (by Joel Oleson with lots of links)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100227091539/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/joelo/archive/2007/07/09/capacity-planning-key-links-and-info.aspx)

[SharePoint 2007 Hardware Specifications and Server Sizing](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815104825/http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/10/17/116101.aspx)

[Determine hardware and software requirements (Office SharePoint Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a *free* search plugin for WSS called **[Search Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/serverproducts/searchserverexpress/features.aspx)** that may help you out.